# Impossible to access a function out of an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm quite new with javascript and I don't understand this problem:

```
$(function() {
    var $tab_title_input = $( "#tab_title"),
    $tab_content_input = $( "#tab_content" );
    var tab_counter = 0;
    var editors = {};
    var tab_current = 0;

    // tabs init with a custom tab template and an "add" callback filling in the content
    var $tabs = $( "#tabs").tabs({
        tabTemplate: "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
        add: function( event, ui ) {
            var tab_content = $tab_content_input.val() || "Tab " + tab_counter + " content.";
            $( ui.panel ).append("<div id=\"editor" + tab_counter + "\" class=\"editor\">" + tab_content + "</div>");
            adjust_size();
            tab_current = ui.index;
            editors[tab_current] = ace.edit("editor" + tab_counter);
            },
        show: function( event, ui ) {
            adjust_size();
            tab_current = ui.index; // zero-based index
            editors[tab_current].resize();
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            adjust_size();
            tab_current = ui.index; // zero-based index
            },

    });
```

The problem is that this line of code:

```
editors[tab_current].resize();
```

breaks everything telling `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'resize' of undefined`.

But editors `editors[tab_current].resize()` is well defined in the add event and `alert(tab_current)` gives me the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd bet money that `editors[tab_current]` returns `undefined`.

Your `alert(tab_current)` may well return a correct value, but that doesn't mean that there's an element of `editors` that corresponds to it. Test it with `alert(editors[tab_current])`, and if it shows `undefined` then go check if the element is being set properly.

Comment: yes it so or similar: the first time it say undefined but then [object Object] and it seem set properly (it works)

Comment: Evidently it doesn't get set properly the first time you go to call it. Trace through your code at runtime to find out why.

Comment: oh and for the first time i mean only when the first tab is created the others one work properly

Comment: Try it in Firefox with the Firebug extension installed. You can trace through every line and set breakpoints.

Comment: i've found the problem: the problem is only with the first tab and i don't know why

Answer (score 0):

I can see two avenues of investigation straight away:

1. What does `ace.edit("editor" + tab_counter)` return?  Does it *always* return an object with a resize method or does it sometimes return undefined?
2. Is `add` always called prior to `show` for any value of `tab_current`?

Comment: 1-) it returns [object object] and it always have a resize method but for security i tried with others and all worked in the add event but not in the sow or select

Comment: 2- ) i think so but when the first tab is created it say undefined for the others object object